# Discord Py. Grab number from a string

Tags: python, discord.py

So, i wanted to make a temp-mute command, and when i do the temp-mute command it should display an embed with the information, such as Nickname, User's ID, Reason and Time this user will be mute.

Now the thing is when i give the command a reason and include an URL, then i try to set the time, and when i send the command it shows the URL in the Time field. Here's a screenshot to explain better
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo7Vv.png)

Here it is the command by the way:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason="", time=""):
        embedMute = discord.Embed(colour=member.color,timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embedMute.set_author(name=f"Mute")
        embedMute.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        embedMute.add_field(name="User:", value=member, inline=False)
        embedMute.add_field(name="ID:", value=member.id, inline=False)
        embedMute.add_field(name="Reason:", value=Reason, inline=False)
        embedMute.add_field(name="Time:", value=time+" hour/s", inline=False)
        embedMute.add_field(name="Logged on:", value=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M"), inline=False)
        embedMute.set_footer(text=f"logged by: {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embedMute)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're adding the reason, I recommend you type the command either like so with quotations around the reason:
`t!mute Simplezes "Reason#1 https://i.imgur.com/1IeETJ5.png" 10`
Or you rewrite the order of your arguments:

## Example:

```py
@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time:int=2, *, reason=""): # declaring that time is an int
                                     # default value ^
        embedMute = discord.Embed(colour=member.color,timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embedMute.set_author(name=f"Mute")
        embedMute.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        embedMute.add_field(name="User:", value=member, inline=False)
        embedMute.add_field(name="ID:", value=member.id, inline=False)
        embedMute.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
        embedMute.add_field(name="Time:", value=time+" hour/s", inline=False)
        embedMute.add_field(name="Logged on:", value=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M"), inline=False)
        embedMute.set_footer(text=f"logged by: {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embedMute)
```

So then you'll be able to write your command as follows:
`t!mute Simplezes 10 Reason#1 https://i.imgur.com/1IeETJ5.png`

The asterisk is making the reason act as a single argument, allowing you to have spaces in the sentence.